# OpenCV - How to deal with an unbalanced dataset when developing an image classifier using a Bag of Visual Words Model?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, dataset, svm

My dataset is represented by a csv file with two attributes: an image path and its label. I have dozens of different labels but the label '51' represents around 34% of the dataset and the label '13' represents around 41%, so just these two labels represent 3/4 of the entire dataset and my classifier ends up classifying everything as '13' (I think I've never seen it classify anything as '51'. Could this be a problem?). How can I deal with this?
I'll leave the code that I currently have here:

```py
from cv2 import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

import sys
sys.path.extend(['../../'])
from src import utils

if __name__ == '__main__':

    DICTIONARY_SIZE = 50
    TRAIN_SIZE = 100
    TEST_SIZE = 100
    DETECTOR = cv.KAZE_create()
    MATCHER = cv.FlannBasedMatcher()
    EXTRACTOR = cv.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(DETECTOR, MATCHER)
    TRAINER = cv.BOWKMeansTrainer(DICTIONARY_SIZE)
    SVM = cv.ml.SVM_create()
    SVM.setType(cv.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
    SVM.setKernel(cv.ml.SVM_LINEAR)
    SVM.setTermCriteria((cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6))

    print("Generating Training and Test Sets...")
    train, test = utils.getTrainingAndTestSets('multiclass.csv', TRAIN_SIZE, TEST_SIZE)

    print("Generating Dictionary...")
    for train_entry in train:
        img_path = train_entry[0]
        img = cv.imread(img_path)
        img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        keypoint, descriptors = DETECTOR.detectAndCompute(img, None)
        if descriptors is not None:
            TRAINER.add(descriptors)

    EXTRACTOR.setVocabulary(TRAINER.cluster())

    print("Preparing Training Data...")
    train_desc = []
    train_labels = []
    for train_entry in train:
        img_path = train_entry[0]
        img_label = int(train_entry[1])
        img = cv.imread(img_path)
        img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        descriptor = EXTRACTOR.compute(img, DETECTOR.detect(img))
        if descriptor is not None:
            train_desc.extend(descriptor)
            train_labels.append(img_label)

    print("Training...")
    SVM.train(np.array(train_desc), cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, np.array(train_labels))

    correct_predictions = 0
    samples_tested = len(test)
    print("Testing...")
    for test_entry in test:
        img_path = test_entry[0]
        real_attribute_id = int(test_entry[1])
        img = cv.imread(img_path)
        img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        feature = EXTRACTOR.compute(img, DETECTOR.detect(img))
        try:
            _, prediction = SVM.predict(feature)
            predicted_attribute_id = int(prediction[0][0])
            if predicted_attribute_id == real_attribute_id:
                print("CORRECT PREDICTION! :)")
                correct_predictions += 1
            else:
                print("INCORRECT PREDICTION... :(")
            print("Predicted Label: " + utils.getLabelFromAttributeID(predicted_attribute_id) + "(" + str(predicted_attribute_id) + ")")
            print("Real Label: " + utils.getLabelFromAttributeID(real_attribute_id) + "(" + str(real_attribute_id) + ")")
        except Exception:
            samples_tested -= 1


    correct_percentage = (correct_predictions / samples_tested) * 100
    print("Test Results: " + "{:.2f}".format(correct_percentage) + "% Correct Predictions.")
```

Feel free to tell me if my current approach has any error. Thanks.

Comment: In an imbalanced dataset situation calculating accuracy as `(correct_predictions / samples_tested) * 100` is meaningless. You need to calculate precision, recall and F1 scores for each of the classes.

Comment: If your classifier allows, you could also add weights to the model to artificially bump up scores of uncommon classes or penalise majority class.